# Create own Package Manager Console commands?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, command, nuget

I'd like to include custom Package Manager Console commands with my NuGet Package. Just like EF-Core is doing recently to generate the context for example.
How can this be done without having to use the default folder "... Documents\WindowsPowerShell\NuGet_profile.ps1"?
I want to generate classes via console so I do not have to develop a Visual Studio extension for it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would pack .pds1/.psm1 files into a `tools` directory inside the NuGet package. Which are automatically available inside the Package Manager Console (the `tools` folder will be added to the `PATH` environment variable).

You can download and inspect the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` for reference, since this is the package that provides the Entity Framework Core commands.

Comment: You can see sample code in https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/tree/main/src/EFCore.Tools/tools